# Topdesk: API response not being registered on my table

Tags: javascript, sql, json, sqlite

I have a code and what I want to do at the moment is retrieving data from my Topdesk API and storing it on my database called ticketsIT. But my database (SQLite) remains empty. I have added one row of mock data just to test it out, but that's it. The real data is not being retrieved.
This is part of my code (some parts were altered for privacy reasons):

```
const fetchDataFromAPI = async () => {
const apiUrl = 'https://mycompany.topdesk.net/tas/api/incidents?query=operatorGroup.name=='IT%20Support'';
   
    try {
        // Make HTTP request to the API
        const authHeader = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from('myuser:mypass').toString('base64');

         // Make HTTP request to the API with Basic Authentication
         const response = await axios.get(apiUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': authHeader
            }
        });

        // Extract relevant data from the API response
        const incidents = response.data?.incidents || [];
       
        // Insert data into the SQLite database
        for (const incident of incidents) {
            const { number, closed, operatorGroup, operator, closedDate } = incident;
            operatorGroup = operatorGroup.name;
            operator = operator.name;
        
            const insertQuery = `INSERT INTO ticketsIT (id, status, operatorGroup, operator, closedDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`;
        
            try {
                await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    db.run(insertQuery, [number, closed, operatorGroup, operator, closedDate], (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error('Error inserting data into the database:', err);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Data inserted into the database successfully for incident:', number);
                        }
                    });
                });
        
                console.log('Data inserted into the database successfully for incident:', number);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error inserting data into the database for incident:', number, error);
            }
        }
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data from the API:', error.message);
    }
};

fetchDataFromAPI();
```

Also, one more detail: I figured that some URLs work on Postman but not on my code and vice-versa (for example, I use %20 on Postman and it works, but on Visual Studio I receive the error "An identifier or keyword cannot immediately follow a numeric literal"). For that reason I have tried several different URLs on my code, but it's being really difficult to know which one should work for sure. Some of them do not give me errors but I get no response on Postman, so I don't know if this could be the problem or if it's something else.

Explained above ^ ...

P.S.: My database (projectDatabase.js) is called ticketsIT and its columns are id, subject, class, operatorGroup, operator, closedDate and request.

I want them to be equivalent to number, NULL, NULL, closed, operatorGroup.name, operator, closedDate, request.

This is an example (part of it, edited for privacy) of the API response:

```
{
    "number": "12345abc",
    "request": "theRequestItself",
    "operator": {
        "id": "9876",
        "name": "John Doe"
    },
    "operatorGroup": {
        "name": "IT Support"
    },

    "completed": false,
    "completedDate": null,
    "closed": false,
    "closedDate": null,
    ...
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, an SQL problem, a JSON problem, or an API problem?

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is, do you know how I can try to discover this? Because I am not receiving any errors on my VScode, Console or anything like that. I have tested the database with mock information and it worked. I have tried to change VALUES (?, ?, ?...) for defined values and it didn't work. But when I SELECT * from tickets, there's nothing there but my mock data, so I really have no idea. I just receive no message at all on the terminal and console. I thought it could be something related to JSON but I don't know.